# One-point-functors and the Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathfrak{Sets}$ be the category of sets, and $\mathfrak{Sch}$ the category of schemes. For any scheme $X$, consider the functor $h_{X}(-)=\mathsf{Hom}_{\mathfrak{Sch}}(-,X):\mathfrak{Sch}\longrightarrow \mathfrak{Sets}$. Consider also the following lemma:

**Lemma (Yoneda):**
*Let $C$ be a category, $A$ an object of $C$ and $F:C^{opp} \longrightarrow \mathfrak{Sets}$ a functor. Let $\mathsf{Nat}(h_{A},F)$ be the set of all natural transformations between $h_{A}$ and $F$. Then there exists a one-to-one correspondance $\mathsf{Nat}(h_{A},F)\cong F(A)$.*

I would like to show that any scheme $X$ can be recovered from $h_{X}$ up to unique isomorphism. Can this fact be proven using the Yoneda lemma?

Comment: What do you mean by "recovered"? The Yoneda embedding is fully faithful and so conservative in particular. Therefore $X$ is unique up to isomorphism, and even up to equality if you know how to recognise $\mathrm{id}_X$.

Comment: Indeed, I have several times heard Yoneda's lemma casually summarized as, "You are who your friends say you are."  The fact that a scheme is completely described by its functor of points is so significant that several important generalizations of schemes (such as algebraic spaces) are defined simply _as_ functors on the category of schemes.

Comment: Why do you restrict to the category to schemes?! Or do you want to construct the ringed space of $X$ from the functor $\hom(-,X)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should come immediately from the Yoneda Lemma. Suppose you have objects $X$ and $Y$. First from Yoneda we know that given any functor $F: C^{opp} \to \textbf{Set}$ that

$$\mathsf{Nat}(h_X,F) = F(X).$$

If you now put $F= h_Y$ then Yoneda in particular says
$$\mathsf{Nat}(h_X,h_Y) = h_Y(X) = \mathsf{Hom}(Y,X).$$

So if you had an isomorphism between the functors $h_X$ and $h_Y$ can you use this to construct an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$?

By the way, this can be seen as a corollary of Yoneda or just simply as the statement that the representing object is unique upto isomorphism. Yoneda actually says a lot more than the latter statement.